# Vanilla Javascript filter function works perfect in one line, but not work at all for other

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I am trying to filter JSON file with plain JavaScript.

```
city = await cities.filter(ea => {
    return ea.city.toLowerCase().includes(searcher.value.toLowerCase()); //example value Belgrade
});

admin = await cities.filter(eb => {
    return eb.admin_name.toLowerCase().includes(searcher.value.toLowerCase()); //example value Beograd
});
```

While filter that goes to city variable works perfect, one that goes to admin variable, witch is Copy-Paste of first one, return error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

and even if I remove toLowerCase function I get same error but (reading 'includes')

this is structure of JSON file:

```
[
 {
  "city": "Tokyo",
  "city_ascii": "Tokyo",
  "lat": 35.6839,
  "lng": 139.7744,
  "country": "Japan",
  "iso2": "JP",
  "iso3": "JPN",
  "admin_name": "Tōkyō",
  "capital": "primary",
  "population": 39105000,
  "id": 1392685764
 },
]
```

Comment: Why are you `awaiting` a `filter` function? It doesn't return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just means `admin_name` doesn't exist, or is `null`/`undefined` for at least one object of your array.

In order to support this, you could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like this:

```
admin = cities.filter(eb => {
    return eb.admin_name?.toLowerCase()?.includes(searcher.value.toLowerCase()); //example value Beograd
});
```

As a side note, `await`ing a non `Promise` value just returns that value, so it's useless in your case.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot!